# Favorited Tag Questions on the Stack Exchange Android app

Tags: feature-request, questions, android-app, tag-watching

It would be nice to show questions based on favorited tags on the Android App, just like the Web application.  The app doesn't handle it right now and this feature would be nice to have.

Comment: Has this been added in the 2+ years since this question? As far as I can tell, it is still not implemented.

Comment: @Joel not added, and never will, I'm afraid. All evidence showing that nobody is working on the android app anymore. Bugs not fixed, so obviously they won't put any efforts into adding new features.

Answer (score 1):

Can't believe this feature has so few votes. I really want just `my tags` mode, sorting by date and without filtering by having answer.

Comment: You can use the `intags:mine` search operator ([according to this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/280393/307988) anyway, I don't use the Android app)

Comment: @Cai That for the tip, but doesn't seem to work in Android app.