# Add "newest (my tags)" filter on Android app

Tags: feature-request, android-app, filtering, question-lists

I think most people who come to Stack Exchange to answer others' questions - they look for the new question according to their favorite tags.

Since such behavior is a default on the Stack Exchange website - the feed of the newest questions in relevant tags would be best for most users.

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no direct way to do that, though you could use the same syntax as you do with the Stack Exchange site search. Just type this in the search textbox and it will show questions with your favorite tags:

```
intags:mine
```

Comment: `intags:mine` is the proper user operator (`infavorites:mine` displays questions that you have favorited, which is not what the question is about) ([source](http://stackoverflow.com/help/searching)).

Comment: @dark Oh, that's right.

Comment: @dark Btw, I don't know why did the reviews reject your edit.

Comment: I quote reasoning of the two rejects, for future reference: 1. This edit deviates from the original intent of the post. Even edits that must make drastic changes should strive to preserve the goals of the post's owner. 2. This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer.

Comment: @darkred true, you can't just remove something like "Currently there is no direct way to do that" and reword an answer as if it was yours. It's not. You found something obvious to fix? Good, fix it, but don't make the answer into something else.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Alright, thanks for the reply.