# Setting to which questions you want to see in app

Tags: feature-request, android-app

It would be nice to define which questions you want to see. Like by tags or something. Now when I go to the questions of a site, I've to do a search everytime. E.g.  [php]

Comment: Very related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217695/add-newest-my-tags-filter-on-android-app

Comment: Indeed. I expected topic suggestions when posting this one in the app's feedback option, but didn't get any.